# What does "access consciousness" mean?

Tags: emotion, educational-psychology

These emotional interventions, which allow contact to be selected faster by the attention mechanism for broadcasting by access consciousness, also allow the various aforementioned CELTS' learning mechanism at a faster pace.

Comment: Could you add the reference to what you are basing yourself on here (by editing your question)?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some searching I believe I have found the passage you are referring to.

The passage you gave is in a dissertation called [The use of emotions in the implementation of various types of learning in a cognitive agent](http://www.archipel.uqam.ca/3798/1/D2114.pdf) by Usef Faghihi of University of Québec.

From what I understand of it from skim reading, the passage you gave was about operations within a particular form of Artificial Intelligence, and the passage is on page 75.

Page 43 has your answer.

> Learning  Intelligent  Distribution  Agent  (LIDA)  (Figure  3.3)  is  a  hybrid  cognitive architecture,  developed  by  Stan  Franklin  and  his  colleagues  at  the  University  of Memphis  (Franklin  and  Patterson,  2006).  LIDA  is  IDA's  successor;  IDA  was  originally conceived  to  assign  new  billets  to  sailors.  In  the  American  Navy,  at  the  end  of  each sailor's  tour  of  duty,  he/she  is  assigned  a  new  billet  (task)  by  a  detailer.  IDA  performs the  detailer's  role.  It  communicates  with  sailors  via  e-mail  and  must  understand sailors'  requirements  and  preferences,  as  weil  as  respect  ail  constraints  of  the  Navy. To  reply  to  the  sailors,  it  has  to  communicate  with  different  databases  (Franklin  et  al., 2005,  Franklin  and  Patterson,  2006).
>
> LIDA's  architecture  is  partly  symbolic  and  partly  connectionist  and  is  equipped with  six  artificial  intelligence  software  technologies:  a  copycat  architecture,  a  sparse distributed  memory,  a  global  workspace,  a  schema  mechanism,  a  behaviour  net,  and a  sub-sumption  architecture.
>
> Franklin  called  LIDA  a  "conscious  agent"  for  its  fundamental  elements  and processes  rely  on  functional  consciousness  as  described  by  Baars  (Baars,  1997). LIDA  is  constructed  with  simple  agents  called  "codelets"  (which  reproduce  Baars' "simple  processors").  **The  central  point  of  the  system  is  the  "access  consciousness",** which  allows  all  resources  to  access  centrally  selected  information  that  is  "broadcast" to  unconscious  processes  (which  guides  the  agent  to  be  stimulated  only  with  the most  relevant  information).